# How to pass an argument with multiple types as an argument to a function in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Typescript newbie here.

A component in React receives a prop of a certain type. This prop is then further used to do a bunch of other stuff.

The component:

```
const ComponentA : SomeComponent<{
   dateVal?: string
}> = ({
   dateVal
}) => {....}
```

`dateVal` is a `string` because there already is some code that requires it to be this way.
I now want to use an existing helper function and pass `dateVal` as an argument.

The helper function:

```
export const helperFunction = (param1?: Param1, date?: Date): string | null => {...}
```

How do I use `helperFunction` since the argument needs to be of type `Date`?
I tried calling it like this `helperFunction(param1, new Date(dateVal))` but I get the error `Argument of type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | number'.`

What is the best way around this? Is there a way in Typescript to pass a parameter by explicitly defining its type? Or can I add some conditional logic to pass the parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `new Date(dateVal)` constructor expects `dateVal` to be a string or a number. You're passing `dateVal` of the type `string | undefined`, since it's optional.

If you're 100% sure that `dateVal` is a string, you can use an exclamation mark to tell TypeScript "I'm sure this isn't `undefined` or `null`", like so:

```js
helperFunction(param1, new Date(dateVal!))
```

Of course, usually you'd use a type guard, and TypeScript would realize `dateVal` has to be a string, for example:

```js
if (!dateVal) {
  // We know dateVal is undefined or the empty string
  return; // return something
}

// TypeScript now knows that dateVal has to be a string
// otherwise the if-statement would've returned earlier
helperFunction(param1, new Date(dateVal))
```

Comment: Oh, so `param!` is a thing, I did not know that!
This solved my problem, thanks!

Comment: It's quite [hidden away](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) in the documentation. It's handy (and only meant for) certain edge cases where TypeScript can't know a variable will be non-null/undefined but where the developer can actually know for sure. E.g. very common when using a callback for `setTimeout`, `array.find`, ...